# Django rest framework; how do you use the ID of a foreign key to create an instance through the serializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two serializers, one for Country and one for my model Foo, I want to save the object by using the foreign key for this model but it errors out whenever I try to validate.

I have this

```
class Actor(TLPWrappedModel, CommentableModel):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=56, unique=True)
    country_of_origin = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)



class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    country_of_origin = CountrySerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Actor
        fields = [
            'id',
            'country_of_origin',
            'label',
       ]


class Country(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=56, unique=True)
    iso_code = models.CharField(max_length=3, unique=True)

class CountrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Country
        fields = [
            'iso_code',
            'label',
        ]
```

And this is what I'm trying to do

```
    serializers = FooSerializer(data={'label': 'Foobar',
                                        'country_of_origin': self.country.id})
    serializers.is_valid()
    print(serializers.errors)
    print(serializers.validated_data)
    serializers.save()
```

But I get this error `{'country_of_origin': {'non_field_errors': [ErrorDetail(string='Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int.', code='invalid')]}}`

is it possible to use the ID of a foreign key to validate and create the object using the serializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can update the to_represent of the FooSerializer to get the desired output

Try

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Actor
        fields = [
            'id',
            'country_of_origin',
            'label',
       ]
    
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        data['country_of_origin'] = CountrySerializer(instance.country_of_origin)
        return data
```

```
 serializers = FooSerializer(data={'label': 'Foobar', 'country_of_origin': self.country})
 serializers.is_valid(raise_expection=True)
 serializers.save()
```

In this I have updated the code to assign the `self.country` as `country_of_origin`. Also, I am using the `raise_expection` in the `is_valid` method. This method will return the errors as 400 response.

Comment: This doesn't quite fixes the issue. FooSerializer would serialize the object into a json like this {'label': 'Foobar', 'country_of_origin': 1} when I want {'label': 'Foobar': 'country_of_origin': {'label': 'usa'}} as an example. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: oh, i have updated the answer. Please try this and let me know if that resolves the issue

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    

    class Meta:
        model = Actor
        fields = [
            'id',
            'country_of_origin',
            'label',
       ]
```

You can safely drop defining the 'country of origin` in the FooSerializer

Comment: Is the only way to make this work whilst also keeping the serialized json expanded to be to use two different serializer classes?

Comment: Absolutely not! there are other ways as well.  I am adding another answer with another approach

Answer (score 1):

contry_of_origin would be an object, and you are passing an id for it.

Do you need a nested serializer? : country_of_origin = CountrySerializer()
For the example that you have given, I would suggest you to change it to PrimaryKeyRelatedField()

Your serializer would look like:

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    country_of_origin = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = Actor
        fields = [
            'id',
            'country_of_origin',
            'label',
       ]
```

Comment: Is the only way to make this work whilst also keeping the serialized json expanded to be to use two different serializer classes?

Comment: You wont need CountrySerializer if you are passing the id in primarykeyrelatedfield. Serailizers are needed only if you plan on viewing/creating/editing that spacific dataset(model)

Comment: I need the CountrySerializer to see the actual contents of the object when it's serialized to a json.

Comment: I think there is some confusion with the requirement. Lets discuss this in chatroom